# ZBar not cropping scan region

Tags: xcode, barcode-scanner, ios7.1, zbar

I'm cropping the scanning region of Zbar via the following code:

```
- (void)startScanning
{
    NSLog(@"Scanning..");

    reader = [AACZBarViewController new];
    reader.readerDelegate=self;
    reader.supportedOrientationsMask = ZBarOrientationMask(UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    reader.showsZBarControls = NO;

    CGFloat x,y,w,h;
    x =0;
    y =0.25;
    w=1;
    h=0.50;

    reader.scanCrop = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h); //Crop scan region
    reader.cameraOverlayView = [self myOverlay];

    ZBarImageScanner *scanner = reader.scanner;
    [scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25 config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE to: 0];

    [self presentViewController:reader animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The problem however is that the program still uses the entire screen area to find a barcode - not the middle 50%. I don't think the issue is the reader.scanCrop method, but as to what the real culprit is, I can't fathom.

Edit:

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the zbar documentation again and noticed it said the x axis on the camera is verticle - not horizontal. Now I'd set the reader to be portrait only but apparently this does not affect the camera in any way. I didn't find a way to change this, but I did manage to crop to the scanning region I wanted.

**The solution:**
If you want the following scan region (x,y,w,h) then you set the rectangle by swapping the x and y and width and height so do this (y,x,h,w). It doesn't seem to crop to the bounding box exactly, but it's close enough for my purposes.